# How to train my model to draw bounding box around text present in image?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, bounding-box, yolo

I am trying to draw bounding_box around the image. I have a different model to predict the class of text detected. Everywhere yolo implementation is based on bounding box+ class prediction. So the loss function they have defined is a loss for class prediction, confidence, and the probability of given class. I just want my loss function to be defined only in terms of the bounding box. Please suggest me how to do it, or suggest me some articles to read.

Comment: I'm confused. If your case, you have 2 classes, text and non-text. So, use Yolo for classifying between those 2 classes and drawing bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

> So the loss function they have defined is a loss for class prediction,
>   confidence, and the probability of given class.

Actually the loss function of YOLO consists of

1. the **classification loss**
2. **the localization loss** (errors between the predicted boundary box and the ground truth)
3. **the confidence loss** (the objectness of the box).

https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/real-time-object-detection-with-yolo-yolov2-28b1b93e2088

If you are looking for accuracy **only for bounding box**, then what you want is called **mAP (mean Average Precision)**. To be able to understand how mAP is calculated will take some time for newcomer in object detection, so I will just put some good link for later study https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/map-mean-average-precision-for-object-detection-45c121a31173.

If you want to visualize the mAP for your YOLO model during training, you can use this popular github repository created by AlexeyAB https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet.

For example you can train your model by inputting `-map` flag like this :

```
./darknet detector train data/obj.data yolo-obj.cfg darknet53.conv.74 -map
```

The chart below will be generated and the red line indicates the mAP and the blue line indicates the average loss of your trained model.

[image]

Finally after training, you can check which weights is the best for you (checking the mAP value)

```
./darknet detector map data/obj.data yolo-obj.cfg backup\yolo-obj_7000.weights
```

The author of this repo writes everything on his github repo so please take a time to read all the steps that you need.

**Additional Information**
I also do the same thing as you do for my current project. I use YOLO only to detect object and draw bounding box. But for the classification I use another CNN model.